# How to filter a table based on %LIKE% values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

So i have tableA and tableB. A is of raw domains data, like http://www.cnn.com, where B has it trimmed up all nice and tidy, like cnn.com. I need to pull websites that aren't in tableB that are in tableA. I imagine a left join with some crazy %LIKE% operator is placed in there.

this is what i have so far but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT tableA.domain, sum(tableA.views) views FROM `tableA` LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.domain %LIKE% tableB.name WHERE tableB.name IS NULL AND GROUP BY tableA.domain ORDER BY views DESC
```

thank you!

Comment: So which is it: mysql, sql or sql-server? And we need to see your 2 tables structure (column names and types). And 'doesn't work'? Error or not what you want or expect.

Comment: PS - you JOIN on things that are equal; then you do a WHERE... LIKE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT tableA.domain, sum(tableA.views) views FROM `tableA` 
 LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.domain  LIKE CONCAT('%', tableB.name ,'%')
 WHERE tableB.name IS NULL 
 GROUP BY tableA.domain 
 ORDER BY views DESC
```

you have two errors in your try.

1- `LIKE CONCAT('%', tableB.name ,'%')`  // you have to use `CONCAT`

2- remove the `AND` before `group by`

Comment: doesnt that just pull exact matches? im trying to see if there is any values that are alike. --> is "espn.com" in http:// www. espn .com?

Comment: espn.com was just an example, i have a multitude of different domains im trying to sift through. how would you go about using tableB and a LIKE %...% operator to be applied to tableA to make it filter like values?                  Thanks!

Comment: i guess i know what you mean try this edited answer.

Comment: i might be implementing it wrong on my end but that does look right. thanks!

Comment: if i was to put a limit of 1000 on the tableA how would i go about doing that? jsut add LIMIT 1000 to the end of the whole bit?

Comment: yeah but i think my tables are too large to push through our server, just realized that is probably my problem and not my syntax :\, ill have to get creative.....it keeps hanging up on 'writing to tmp table'

Answer (score 0):

The `%` are suppose to be around the value you're comparing to, not the LIKE keyword itself.

It should be something like

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE column LIKE '%pattern%';
```

Comment: i could just add them like '%tableB.name%'?